# How to share .java files between projects

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I am fairly new to Java, so I might be missing the obvious here.

I want to pull `.java` files (not JARs) from a folder that is "external" to the project. I am developing the MainProject and the shared java files concurrently. Later I will want to use the shared files in another project (most likely also as `.java` files since that other project will be related to the first - i.e. more concurrent development).

I can't work out how to use a `.java` file from the SharedJava folder in the MainProject. I have tried what is suggested on Stack Overflow etc. to no avail.

I have set up a new project with folders like so:

[image]

I have created VSCode Java Projects in both folders, although for the `SharedJava` I didn't include any build tools. Maybe that is an issue?

Both projects appear in the JAVA PROJECTS section in VSCode.

Expanded, it looks like below, and as an initial test the highlighted java file is the one I would like to import into the MainProject.

[image]

The SharedClass.java file:

```java
package messaging;

public class SharedClass {
  public void echoMessage(String msg) {
    System.out.println("SharedClass.echoMessage() said: " + msg);
  }
}
```

What I am trying to do for my test is in this MainProject App.java file:

```java
package com.flowt;

public class App {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );

        // How to import SharedClass ?
        SharedClass sharedClass = new SharedClass();
        sharedClass.echoMessage("Hello XYZ");
    }
}
```

My `MainProject.code-workspace` file is this:

```json
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "."
        },
        {
            "path": "../SharedJava/flowtshared"
        }
    ],
    "settings": {
        "java.project.sourcePaths": [
            "src",
            "../SharedJava/flowtshared/src"
        ]
    }
}
```

So, what do I need to do to be able to import `SharedClass.java` into MainProject? (without creating a symlink!)

Comment: My advice is not to share source files between projects like this -- learn to use maven and install your common code as a library in your local maven repository.

Comment: Thanks, I am using Maven and did think about that option. What stopped me was the thought that each time I changed something in the SharedJava (which would be often, at this stage of development), I would need to rebuild a jar. Maybe that is not such a big deal? Or maybe that is not even true? So, thanks, I am very open to learning "best practice" at this early stage of my Java journey. :-)

Comment: Also, I did watch one tutorial on that and just setting it all up was a huge amount of work. Maybe that was a bad tutorial.

Comment: You would need to rebuild the jar -- `mvn install` puts the jar in your local repository. You'd use a SNAPSHOT version of the jar while you're developing. Perhaps the tutorial you watched included setting up a maven repository you can deploy to -- you don't need to do that for local development (I assume you are pushing your source code to github/bitbucket or similar?)

Comment: @tgdavies: yes, the tutorial implied a remote maven repo was the only option, but that was probably my misunderstanding. Yes, using GitHub for my code. Thanks for your pointers.

Comment: Hi Murrah, If you find the solution, Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Comment: @JialeDu Thanks, yes, I will. I am currently learning more about Maven as suggested by @ tgdavies before I post a solution that as yet is not clear! ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Got it working.

Firstly: The best explanation I found for understanding Maven (that included a good example of multi-module projects) is here:
https://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/index.html

It is quite old, and the sample code wont work because it references APIs that no longer exist. However, the explanations are really clear and the sample code files still exist as a reference.

Maybe if you know of more up-to-date references that are as good, you can put a comment below.

For other Java newbies I offer the following...

The final result was done partly using VSCode functionality and partly hand customised. If I understood the VSCode java extensions better maybe I could have done it all using the extensions.

The short version is as below and the resulting files and folders etc are shown further down.

1. Create a new Java Project for the `parent`. Use the Maven quick-start archetype. For this sample I just used all the defaults, apart from my groupId, etc.
2. Keep the `pom.xml` file and delete the rest.
3. Add `<packaging>pom</packaging>` to the `pom.xml` file as per example below.
4. Inside the `parent` project, create the `shared` project, using the same groupId as the parent. When asked, add the project to the workspace. Delete the `App.java` file if you wish.
5. In the `shared` pom.xml I removed the `<groupId>` section. Note that Maven includes the `<parent>` block.
6. Inside the `parent` project, create the `mainapp` project, using the same groupId as the parent. When asked, add the project to the workspace.
7. In the `mainapp` pom.xml I removed the `<groupId>` section. Note that Maven includes the `<parent>` block.
8. In the `mainapp` pom.xml, add a `<dependency>` block for the `shared` project, as per example below.
9. If you go back to the `parent` project's `pom.xml`, and scroll to the end, you should see that VSCode has added a block like this:

```
<modules>
  <module>shared</module>
  <module>mainapp</module>
</modules>
```

which you can move to the top to make it more visible.

10. Add your test class (eg PrintMessage.java) to your `shared` project in its own folder (eg messaging).
11. Update your `mainapp` `App.java` file to include your shared class as per the example.
12. From the parent project root run `mvn clean install`. This adds the jars to the local Maven repo (the location of the local repo is as printed in the terminal output).

At this point I find I needed to close and reopen the VSCode window so that the Java Projects section sorts itself out and the 3 projects appear there. If I didn't do that I got "classpath" errors.

Then, I could test by opening the `App.java` file and using VSCode to `Run java`. The terminal shows:

```
Hello World!
PrintMessage.echoMessage() echoed: I was called from Main app
```

I notice if I edit the `PrintMessage.java` file (eg change the output message) I can run the `App.java` file without recompiling and the change shows up. Cool.

==== Code samples ====

(I deleted the `src/test` and `target` folders for clarity)

[image]

The `parent` pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <name>The Parent project for my test multi modules</name>

  <groupId>com.flowt.multitest</groupId>
  <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <modules>
    <module>shared</module>
    <module>mainapp</module>
  </modules>

  <dependencies>

    <!-- The rest of this file is as normal ... -->
```

The `shared` pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <!-- Refer to the parent pom.xml -->
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.flowt.multitest</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <!--
    Since we have a parent we leave this out
    because it is pulled from the parent pom.xml

    <groupId>com.flowt.shared</groupId>
  -->
  <artifactId>shared</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <!-- The rest of this file is as normal ... -->
```

The `mainapp` pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <!-- Refer to the parent pom.xml -->
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.flowt.multitest</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>mainapp</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>
      1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- Here you must include the shared project as a dependency -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.flowt.multitest</groupId>
      <artifactId>shared</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <!-- The rest of this file is as normal ... -->
```

`PrintMessage.java`

```java
package com.flowt.messaging;

public class PrintMessage {
  public String echoMessage(String msg) {
    return "PrintMessage.echoMessage() echoed: " + msg;
  }
}
```

`App.java`

```java
package com.flowt.app;

// This class is in the shared project: shared/src/main/java/com/flowt/messaging/PrintMessage.java
import com.flowt.messaging.PrintMessage;

/**
 * Hello world!
 */
public class App {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );

        // The shared class
        PrintMessage printMessage= new PrintMessage();
        String echo = printMessage.echoMessage("I was called from Main app");
        System.out.println(echo);
    }
}
```

I hope that helps and any expert advice on structuring an app is most welcome.

Go well,
Murray